# Best way to separate features by user type

Tags: architecture

How do you guys design the architecture of your software for when you have to restrict/modify features depending on the user type? For example, lets say we have 3 user types:

- Free
- Premium
- Business

And the feature that we are implementing an API for Image upload.

Now the tricky part is:

- Free users can upload 10 images.
- Premium users can upload 100 images
- Business users can upload 1000 images.

Well, I know that I can do an 'if' on the method that handles the request, but since there are many other similar cases (features that depend on the user type), I wanted to find out a better and more scalable solution for this problem.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use polymorphism, that is, have different subclasses that implement the same same method differently for each case.

For example, you can have an `User` class, with subclasses `FreeUser`, `PremiumUser` and `BusinessUser`, and when you call `User.UploadImage`, each subtype of user would have different limits.

The base class would contain all of the other metods (similar cases).

Comment: Yes, this works. But I already have two different types of users. One for Admin and other for User. Also, I made a bad decision of using the Anemic Domain Model, so all the business logic is implemented on Service Classes.. Perhaps if I just create a Service for each Plan/User type and inject it on the user according to its type, I could maybe satisfy the same purpose... The only thing that I am afraid of is adding unnecessary complexity. What do you think?

Comment: Polymorphism is the exact opposite of "type-based conditionals": https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism

Comment: Yes, I know. And is definitely the way to go. I will restructure my entities and the current architecture. Thank you very much!

Comment: You could also have a `PlanPolicyService` service where policies for every plan type can be configured. These could be associated with a Map or using a predicate to avoid if statements. Code would look like `planPolicyService.canUploadImages(PlanType.Free, imageCount)`. The advantage of this strategy is that rules can be set dynamically (e.g. loaded from a file or DB).

Comment: @plalx Representing business rules and use cases as objects is something I consider best practice, although I still don't use them much, I confess.

Comment: @heltonbiker Well, it's not using objects that bothers me, it's the inheritance part. You do not need an entirely hierarchy of specialized User types if the only thing that really changes are the rules governing the same set of operations. It's better to use composition instead and having a seperate dedicated `PlanPolicyService` allows that or any other strategy that externalizes the rules. You could call on the aggregate like `user.UploadImage(image, planPolicyService)`.